# Images are successfully uploaded to database and display in directory but it won't display on php page

Tags: php, image, upload, display

Images are successfully uploaded to database and display in a directory but it won't display on the php page. Images show up as broken images on the php page. Help me make them display on the php page. I followed a tutorial and watched it many times to make sure there are no errors causing the broken images. Been trying to fix it for days but it won't display images. I'm using XAMPP on a Mac OS. Please look through my codes and let me know why it won't display the images on php.

`marketplace_upload.inc.php` starts here:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $newFileName = $_POST['filename'];

    if (empty($newFileName)) {
        $newFileName = "gallery";

        } else {
            $newFileName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $newFileName));
        }

        $imageTitle = $_POST['filetitle'];
        $imagePrice = $_POST['fileprice'];


        $file = $_FILES['file']; 

        $fileName = $file["name"];
        $fileType = $file["type"];
        $fileTempName = $file["tmp_name"];
        $fileError = $file["error"];
        $fileSize = $file["size"];


        $fileExt = explode(".", $fileName);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

        $allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

        if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
            if ($fileError === 0) {
                if ($fileSize < 2000000) {
                    $imageFullName = $newFileName . "." . uniqid("", true) . "." . $fileActualExt;
                    $fileDestination = "../img/gallery/" . $imageFullName;

                    include_once "dbh.inc.php";

                    if (empty($imageTitle) || empty($imagePrice)) {
                        header("Location:../gallery.php?upload=empty");
                        exit();
                    } else {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery;"; 
                        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                            echo "SQL statement failed!";
                        } else {
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                            $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                            $setImageOrder = $rowCount + 1;

                            $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (titleGallery, priceGallery, imgFullNameGallery, orderGallery) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
                        }
                            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                            echo "SQL statement failed!";
                        } else {
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $imageTitle, $imagePrice, $imageFullName, $setImageOrder);
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                            move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDestination);
                            header("Location: ../gallery.php?upload=success");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "File size is too big!";
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "You had an error!";
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            echo "You need to upload a proper file type!";
            exit();
        }
```

[Screenshot of gallery.php codes where images are supposed to be displayed. It won't let me paste the codes here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIjVm.png)

I would like any uploaded images on my upload website to display in localhost too.

Comment: Show your `directory` structure, as well as code where you are `displaying` your image

Comment: I added a screenshot at the end because it won't let me paste those codes. Please click on link towards the end of my post to see gallery.php codes.

Comment: its in xampp/htdocs/logincodes/firstlogin/img/gallery

Comment: Your `<img>` tag should be like this `<img src=“img/gallery/'.row['imgFullNameGallery'].'”>`

Comment: I made the changes you suggested about the <img> tag and it hasn't changed: it shows broken images on the php page (gallery.php).

Comment: Where is your `gallery.php` located, is it on same place where your `img` folder is?

Comment: Yes. My gallery.php is in the same folder as img folder. They are both in a folder called firstlogin. Right next to each other.

Comment: try to echo this -> `echo img/gallery/row['imgFullNameGallery'];` ,see if it has something in or not .

Comment: Thank you so much. I have made some progress. Its showing the images I already uploaded after I added the echo codes you suggested. But when I tried to upload a new image its showing broken images again. How can I fix that? So that it displays images that are already uploaded to the upload website and the future uploads? I want anyone to be able to upload to that directory from anywhere when I decide to go live. –

Comment: After I made the above changes the images won't display or go to the directory folder where its been going img/gallery/. I need to fix that too. I appreciate the help.

Comment: edit your question with what all changes have you made till now ,

Comment: It won't let me edit my above comment. So I'll just post another one. This is what I changed in the img src quotes to: <img src="img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].'">

Comment: may it's because some value in your `imgFullNameGallery` column is `null` , so sometimes it shows image and sometimes not , so to solve this you can always check if your `imgFullNameGallery` is `empty` or `not` before trying to `show` image in your page .

Comment: I don't have that issue when I click on my html files from another project I did that is in htdocs. But with php it does this. The images do exist. So I am using the same images I have used in the past. So I know they aren't broken images. But they are broken images when I try to upload them to the site.

Comment: Fist thing to look at is the HTML being generated for your image in your web browser. So what do you get when you perform a "view source" on your HTML? You need to see what the browser is seeing.

Comment: I'm not asking about html. I am asking about php. I'm not having any issues with html files.

Comment: Hmm did you know that PHP generates HTML so it shows in your web browser. Let's try this then, what do you mean by a "broken image". What does "broken" mean - what do you see that indicates it's "broken"?

Comment: It shows a blank box with a small icon of a broken image. The images that are currently there right now display after I changed the img tag to what Swati suggested. But when I try to upload the same image before and after deleting an image, this time it won't upload to the directory (img/gallery/) where I set it to upload the image and doesn't display in same php page: it shows a blank box with a tiny broken image icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who helped me or tried to help me. I finally solved the problem. The reason why my images weren't displaying on my php page is because I hadn't change the permissions. Once I changed the permissions to read and write my codes started doing what I want them to do.